# Docker mkimage_yum.sh for centos 7 fails

Tags: docker, centos7, yum

A little confused at the moment. I've got docker on one my servers and as it doesn't have internet access, I'm trying to build a base image for centos7.4. The nice Docker site has a mkimage_yum.sh script for this purpose, but it consistently fails when it tries running:

yum -c /tmp/mkimage_yum.sh.gnagTv/etc/yum.conf --installroot=/tmp/mkimage_yum.sh.gnagTv -y clean all

with a "No enabled repos" error. The thing is, if I enter "yum repolist" I get back 17 entries, and I have manually tried to set several repos to enabled. Yet, this command still fails, and I do not understand what could be missing.

### Anybody have some idea of what I can so this succeeds?

Jay

Comment: what are the contents of the file `/tmp/mkimage_yum.sh.gnagTv/etc/yum.conf`? You are using a different config for this command so you checking `yum repolist` is not telling you if any repos exists in this config. You should try `yum -c /tmp/mkimage_yum.sh.gnagTv/etc/yum.conf repolist`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this was failing, the docker file for mkimage_yum.sh does not contain the proper code if you're storing your repos in /etc/yum.repos.d, it assumes that everything is in /etc/yum.conf. This is really not correct, and it causes one of the later yum clean operations to fail. I fixed it, but I cannot upload the change as the server has no internet access.